# Could someone recommend best settings and plugins to Enable in JetBrains IntelliJ Idea for beginner

Tags: java, ide, installation, intellij-idea

I am a new to IntelliJ Idea from Jetbrains and the installer asks me various questions at first launch. Though i managed Subversion/Version control system settings in first window other seem alien to me. Can i have a experienced hand at completing other steps. I am used to visual studio and .net and C#. But Java for first time, hence such a subjective question, mostly i want to develop Google data, android , java webapps[so database comes along], console application[does java have one??] couple of screenshots from installation 
[image: Scrren1]

**Screen2**

[image: This is window 2]

**Screen 3**

[image: This is screen3]

**Screen 4**

[image: This is screen 4]

I did manage find out what other's were but these bother me. I haven't completed the steps yet waiting for answers to complete and finish the installation

Comment: Well, it's not do or die.  As mentioned in the dialog, you can just uncheck them later if you find you don't need them.  (and vice-versa, of course)

Comment: @Kirk but i thought not to disturb it later

Comment: recommend one plugin if you are using emacs. https://github.com/whunmr/emacsIDEAs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given what you want to do with the IDE, I'd recommend getting at least the following:

GWT, GAE, Hibernate, SQL, and whatever App servers you plan on using for deployment. Also, you can always add those plugins later if and when needed. I've noticed that overloading the IDE with lots of plugins slows IDEA down quite a bit so be selective.

Comment: well you did answer the question

Answer (score 1):

You always have the option to add anything you wish later on (look for the "wrench" button on the menu bar).

I don't use all the Java EE app server options, because I know I'm not likely to use WebSphere and some of the others.

I use Git and Subversion for source code management, so those are enough for me.

Comment: not the best answer but certainly deserves a vote Up thanks for the head tip :)